# Timeout per unit-test class supported?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, xunit, xunit.net

In NUnit I can add a `[Timeout(5000)]` attribute *at the `TestFixture` (test class) level* to specify an upper limit for *each* test method in that class.

In xUnit, I know I can do something similar, but at the test method level: `[Fact(Timeout=5000)]`.

My question is: can I apply a timeout at the test class level with xUnit ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may not be the answer you would like to see but for what it is worth ...

The recommendation here is to create your own replacement for FactAttribute which derives from FactAttribute and sets up any default values you want (like timeout).

Reference: http://xunit.codeplex.com/workitem/9727

Comment: xUnit 2.0 (which is being worked on) will support timeouts. See the list of features: http://xunit.codeplex.com/discussions/390453